# How to handle ASP.NET forms where javascript plugin is generating alternative input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have a ASP.NET MVC webpage that submits a form with ajax like this :

```
function ValidateFormAndAjaxSubmit(formId, callingElement) {

    if (IsNotDblClick(callingElement.id)) {
        var _form = $("#" + formId);

        var validator = _form.validate();
        var anyError = false;

        anyError = !_form.valid();

        if (anyError) {
            window.latestClick = '';
            return false; // exit if any error found    
        }

        $.post(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function (data) {

            if (data.success && data.redirectUrl.length > 0) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
            }
            else {

                var isValid = validateResponse(_form, data);

                window.latestClick = '';
            }
        })
    }
}
```

All control in the form is generated with helpers like Html.TextBoxFor and so on and this works great.

The problem is that a jquery plugin(Select2) will turn a regular textbox into a list like this :

```
<div class="floatLeft">
            <label class="controlTitleContainer" for="Url">Taggar</label>
            <br style="clear:both;">
            <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi bigdrop" id="s2id_txtTagBox" style="width: 408px">    <ul class="select2-choices" style="">  <li class="select2-search-choice">    <div>Film                </div>    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a></li><li class="select2-search-choice">    <div>Hund                </div>    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a></li><li class="select2-search-field">    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="select2-input valid" tabindex="0" style="width: 10px;">  </li></ul></div><input style="width: 408px; display: none;" class="bigdrop" id="txtTagBox" name="Tags" type="text" value="">
        </div>
```

You can here see that the textbox is set to display none while the added tags is shown like a ul list. In this case I have added Film and Hund to the list.

I need these values to be sent to the service(with the above ajax call), the question is how?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the documentation, select2 is designed work with select lists, not textboxes. Try generating a select list instead of a textbox.

Look at the source for "Multi Valued Select Boxes" in the examples, the underlying markup is a select box, but the plugin generates a div to make it look like a textbox.